# Scala and Hive: best way to write a generic method that works with all types of Writable

Tags: scala, hadoop, generics, hive

I am playing with writing Generic UDFs for Hive in Scala. My first test is to write a function to sum arrays (complex data type).

My stub of the code looks like this (Since this is a stub, please ignore the usage of `asInstanceOf` :D):

```
...

class SumElements extends GenericUDF {

  protected val expectedCategories: Array[Category] = Array(ObjectInspector.Category.LIST)
  protected var listInspector: ListObjectInspector = _

  @throws(classOf[UDFNullArgumentException])
  @throws(classOf[UDFArgumentLengthException])
  @throws(classOf[UDFArgumentTypeException])
  override def initialize(inspectors: Array[ObjectInspector]): ObjectInspector = {
    ...
    listInspector = inspectors(0).asInstanceOf[ListObjectInspector]
    ...
  }

  @throws(classOf[HiveException])
  override def evaluate(args: Array[DeferredObject]): AnyRef = {

    val list: util.List[_] = listInspector.getList(args(0).get)
    val listLength: Int = listInspector.getListLength(list)

    val tmp: IndexedSeq[Int] = for {
      i <- 0 until listLength
    } yield listInspector.getListElement(list, i).asInstanceOf[IntWritable].get

    tmp.sum.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
  }

  override def getDisplayString(args: Array[String]): String = "SumElements(Array<Numeric>)"
}
```

Basically, I have to read each element of the list, cast it to `IntWritable` and then `get` the primitive. The code above works and returns the correct sum but is not generic: it only works for `Int`.

Trying to create a generic I got to this:

```
class HadoopList(list: util.List[_], listInspector: ListObjectInspector) {

  def fromWritableToPrimitive[W <: Writable, N]: IndexedSeq[N] = {

    val listLength: Int = listInspector.getListLength(list)

    val tmp: IndexedSeq[N] = for {
      i <- 0 until listLength
    } yield listInspector.getListElement(list, i).asInstanceOf[W].get.asInstanceOf[N]

    tmp
  }

}
```

But turns out that the `Writable` interface does not enforce the function `get`! It was quite surprising to find out that the concrete Writable types are not guaranteed to have a `get` method.

My questions are:

1. Am I missing something? Is there a superclass of IntWritable that provides the contract `get` so that I can use generically?
2. Why Java seems to cast IntWritable to Int automatically and Scala do not? Java examples don't have the casting step
3. Is there a better Scala-way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not written in Scala, looking at generic UDAFs in hive itself such as [GenericUDAFAverage](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFAverage.java) or [GenericUDAFHistogramNumeric](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFHistogramNumeric.java), it seems they turn any primitive numeric input into Double (using [PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils.getDouble](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive/PrimitiveObjectInspectorUtils.html#getDouble(java.lang.Object,org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.PrimitiveObjectInspector))) and then operate on doubles.

Another option is to find the type during run-time (by checking isInstanceOf against each numeric primitive type) and then calling a generic function.

Comment: I will check the time at runtime as you suggested since there's no possibility to do it generically due to the issue explained in the question

Comment: Just to let you know that I solved my issue using Shapeless' Typeable and TypeCase and it works like a charm!